# Why Von Schicksal ordered to kill Lindow?

Tags: god-eater

In the last episode of the 2015 anime series, a man tells that Lindow was killed as he ordered. Why Von Schicksal ordered to kill Lindow?

Answer (score 1):

Because lindu had been spying on von and infiltrated the 'aigis project' (probably misspelled that) and saw what Von was really doing.